# Find the selected elements and return only the desired property array without each

Tags: jquery, properties, find

I am unaware if this possible. But the online search I did gave me 0 results. From the conventional `find` we can get the array of elements from the document like so `$(document).find("iframe")`.

Is it possible to get an array of selected property from these elements instead. Lets say the above query returns 3 iframe elements,

```
<iframe src="1"/>
<iframe src="2"/>
<iframe src="3"/>
```

Is it possible to just to get the `src` value of those instead of the whole element from a single query **without** using an `each` loop.

I tried `$(document).find("iframe").prop("src")`. But that only returns the `src` of the first `iframe`, not the rest.

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

> Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

```
var arr = $(document).find("iframe").map(function(){
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) il check on this and get back :)